# Is CE(X, Y) equivalent to H(X) + H(Y)?

Tags: probability, distributions, entropy, information-theory, cross-entropy

From my understanding mutual information can be defined in the following ways:

[1]:
$I(X;Y)=H(X)+H(Y)-H(X,Y)$ where $H(X), H(Y)$ are marginal entropies and $H(X,Y)$ is the joint entropy.

[2]:
$I(X;Y)=D_{KL}(p(x, y)||p(x)p(y))$ which is the KL divergence between the joint distribution and the product distribution.

From the definition of cross entropy: $CE(p(x, y), p(x)p(y)) = D_{KL}(p(x, y)||p(x)p(y))+H(p(x, y))$.

Considering this with [2]: $I(X;Y) = CE(p(x, y), p(x)p(y)) - H(p(x, y))$.

Now equating it to [1] we get that the cross entropy is equivalent to the sum of the two marginal entropies.

However, this appears to contradict the definition of cross entropy. Can anyone help to identify what is the problem in the above reasoning?

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's some confusion with the notation.  $CE(X,Y)$ is not the same as $CE(p(x, y), p(x)p(y))$.  The first term is not equal to the sum of entropies but the second term is.

Intuitively, $CE(p(x, y), p(x)p(y))$ measures the bits needed if an encoding scheme is used based on $p(x)p(y)$ (treating the two random variables independently) when the true distribution is $p(x, y)$.  The bits needed is $H(X) + H(Y)$ if we encode the two random variables separately